# I don't have EF CORE BUT both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I have a solution with 4 projects.

- MODEL - .net (Entity Framework 6)
- SERVICE - .net
- Web (webApi) - .net
- WebCore (Angular UI) - .net core

At the very beginning I accidentally installed EF on WebCore project so EF Core was installed but then I uninstalled it. I have no issues since then. On packages manager I don't see it installed any more.

At packages console, I run

```
Enable-EntityFramework -vervose -force
```

An I get an error:

> Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed"

Is it possible that it was somehow not totally uninstalled?

Any ideas?

MODEL project `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

SERVICE project `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Unity" version="5.9.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Unity.Abstractions" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Unity.Container" version="5.9.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Unity.Interception" version="5.9.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

Web PROJECT `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

WebCore PROJECT

no `packages.config` here

Comment: Check WebCore csproj file `PackageReference`s (or use VS NuGet Package Manager) for `Microssoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package.